# Languages won't show up

Tags: language

Ok, so I'm trying to set my system general language to pt-BR, I already downloaded pt language pack with Language Support app, but no languages are shown on System Settings/Language & Region, just a "blank" window. Even when I tried to download English packages the language won't show up on settings, so I really think the trouble is something about languages not showing up on settings, because I already checked others questions with similar problems and followed its steps, but again, nothing works. What is going on? How can I set my system language to pt-BR?

Here's some screenshots:

Language Support app:[image: Language Support app]

System Settings/Language & Region:[image: Language Support app]

"FIX":

The very last line of the sidebar has a "+" button, just click it and search the preferred language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same thing happening as well... My workarournd in the "SystemSettings" window is click on "unlock"button in the right upper corner as admin and add a language on the "+" button on the left corner. WHen I added my language this way somehow all other languages where shown as well at this point.

Comment: YEAH, I'm a <redacted>, I just saw that "+" button and ran to this post to share how I "solved the problem", then I found your answer. hahaha thx man!

Comment: @Leonardo avoid using profanity, please.

Comment: BTW, you can mark this as solved by ticking this answer.

Answer (score -1):

click the + sign in the bottom left corner and you can add languages.