# Not being able to change language settings

Tags: settings

When I try to change language settings in Settings app I can't do anything, it first asks me for password to unlock all of the features,
and after that i can't change anything.
[image: 1]
I hope you can help me, I'm using Elementary OS 0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, it's already answered on this link: [Languages won't show up](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/11964/languages-wont-show-up)

But just to save you some "work", you can get the solution by clicking the "+" button on the bottom of the left sidebar, then all possible languages will show up.

Ah, I have a question for you, what's the theme you're using?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The theme I'm currently using is this:https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1167049/

Comment: No problem man. Mark my answer as accepted!